# Getting factors using recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, factors

The output was correct but it keeps on displaying `-1` at the end of the factors  from time to time (infinite looping). I know there's something wrong with the `while` loop inside the recursion method but I don't know what it is. How can I stop the recursive call after getting the final answer? What should I use instead of a `while` loop?

```
public static void main() {
    int num;
    System.out.print("\fInput:");
    num = kb.nextInt();
    int temp = 1;
    factors(num, temp);
}

public static void factors(int num, int temp) {
    int count = 2;

    while (temp != num) {
        if ((num % count) == 0) {
            System.out.print(count + " * ");
            factors(num / count, temp * count);
        } else
            count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you you want your code to do?

Comment: I need to get and display the factors of a given number.

Comment: Okay,  you got a working example in your answers, there are plenty of ways to do this, but I guess it's enough Karl's by now, if you are not looking for a specific solving method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need a recursion here. If you use recursion, you will always start new with `count = 2`, even if you already checked bigger values.

So, instead of

```
factors(num/count, temp*count);
```

I would just use

```
num = num/count;
```

Second, as Attila already said, you don't need the temp parameter and the real check you need is whether `num != 1` is true.

If you really want to use recursion, there would be a better way: Pass the method `factors` the counter so that you don't always have to start with 2. In this case, you don't need any loop:

```
public static void main()
{
    int num;
    System.out.print("\fInput:");
    num=kb.nextInt();
    int count=2;
    factors(num, count);

}



public static void factors(int num, int count)
{  
    if (num == 1)
        return;

    if((num%count)==0)
    {
        System.out.print(count+ " * ");
        factors(num/count, count);
    }
    else 
        factors(num,count+1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! You got it :) Thank you for all your help :) I'll trace this code and will analyze how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Your stop condition (temp!=num) will never be false.
When you get the final factor and you'd like to stop, you will call factors(1, "the original number"), so the while loop will go on.

You should try instead:

```
while (num != 1)
```

And the temp parameter is not needed.

Comment: Thank you. yes, I realized that the temp variable was useless. :) I tried your while ( num != 1 ) but it's still infinite looping. I really don't get it why the while loop won't turn into false, I can't see anything wrong. I'm still learning how to use recursion method.

Comment: Thanks for all your help :)  Got it. I'll practice more in using recursion method. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As other's pointed out, `while (temp!=num)` will never be `false` and the program will continue looping endlessly. Karl_Costa's solution works well, however, you can still use your while loop for counting purposes as shown. And as other's pointed out, there's no need for using `temp`.

Here's another working solution-

```
public static void main() {
    int num;
    System.out.print("\fInput:");
    num=kb.nextInt();
    System.out.print("1");  // To always print 1 as a factor.
    factors(num, 2);
}

public static void factors(int num, int count) {
    while(num%count != 0 && num>count) {
        count++;
    }
    System.out.print(" * " + count);
    if(num==count) {
        return;
    }
    if(num%count==0)
        factors(num/count, count);
    else {
        factors(num/count, count+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class RecursiveFactors
{
    static void factors(int a, int n)
    {
        if(n%a == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(a);
        }    

        if(a<=n)
            factors(a+1, n);
    }    

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        factors(1,25);
    }
}
```